# Required parameter is undefined in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Whenever I try to load a page specific script with RequireJS, it will tell me that `Builds` is undefined.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs(["../../js/builds/builds"], function(Builds) {
        console.log(Builds);
        Builds.createFunc(window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1))
    });
</script>
```

> js/builds/builds.js

```
"use strict";

define(["../../classes/builds/builds"], (Builds) => {
    const Create = (classID) => {
        return new Builds(classID);
    }

    return {
        createFunc: Create
    }
});
```

> classes/builds/builds.js

```
"use strict";

define(() => {
    return class Builds {
        constructor(arg) {
            this.arg = arg;
            this.init();
        }

        init() {
            console.log("Build loaded with class ID " + this.arg);
        }
    }
});
```

The only time I've got it to work is when I bind `Create` to `window` but that's not what I want to do. I want to be able to access the `Builds` parameter in my page script.

Folder structure:

> resources (where the source files are, I'm compiling them with WebPack)

`resources/js/app/modules/builds/builds.js` compiles into `public/js/builds/builds.js`

[image]

> public folder

[image: https://image.prntscr.com/image/ysoZDj8DQBitkY65lZuLHQ.png]

Config:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "js/lib",
    paths: {
        app: "../app"
    }
});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is your folder structure? Can you provide your requirejs configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working but I put all the files in one scripts folder except for the index.html. Four .js files: require.js, main.js, builds.js and class.js. But I did not use webpack. I was just testing if your code was correct (I have never used requireJS, before).

Index.html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script data-main="./scripts/main" src="./scripts/require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
    console.log(Builds);
    Builds.createFunc(window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1))
});
```

builds.js:

```
"use strict";

define(["./class"], (Builds) => {
    const Create = (classID) => {
        return new Builds(classID);
    }

    return {
        createFunc: Create
    }
});
```

class.js:

```
"use strict";

define(() => {
    return class Builds {
        constructor(arg) {
            this.arg = arg;
            this.init();
        }

        init() {
            console.log("Build loaded with class ID " + this.arg);
        }
    }
});
```